# How to join Enum with LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, enums

I have user table (Default ApplicationUser Table from `IdentityUser` by ASP.CORE)
and I have added additional field for RoleType. There is also an Enum I added to specify Role Definition.

```
public enum Roles
{
    Administrator = 1,
    Headquarters = 2,
    Branch = 3,
    Driver = 4,
    Client = 5
}
```

Now I want to show all the users in a view as a table along with role description.

I am unable to make LINQ query with Enum & User table using LINQ join.

Comment: You want to get the *enum name* from its value, not join with the enum. Why send the enums to the server when you can just call `Enum.GetName` once you have the results? You can add a read-only `RoleName` property to your class, eg `RoleName => Enum.GetName(typeof(Roles),RoleId)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos +1 Sir. Your answer really helped solving the problem with clean code.

Answer (score 6):

To get the list of Roles from the enum use:

```
var roles = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Roles)).Cast<Roles>()
        .Select(r => new { Value = (int)r, Name = r.ToString() }).ToList();
```

you can then use this in your Linq query, for example:

```
var roles = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Roles)).Cast<Roles>()
        .Select(r => new { Value = (int)r, Name = r.ToString() }).ToList();

var users = from u in ApplicationUser
        join r in roles on u.Role equals r.Value
        select new {Name = u.Name, RoleId = u.Role, RoleDescription = r.Name} ;
```

> A simpler way without the `Enum.GetValues` is:

```
var users = from u in ApplicationUser
        select new {Name = u.Name, RoleId = u.Role, RoleDescription = (Roles)r.Role.ToString()} ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xx = from u in _context.Users
         .Select(x => new ApplicationUserList 
                { Firstname = x.Firstname, 
                  RoleType = ((Roles)x.RoleId).ToString() 
                });
```

Comment: ApplicationUser is a base class for users. I cannot directly use it in LINQ

Comment: where is the data coming from... EF?

Comment: Yes, the data is coming from EF and that class inherited from Identity user.

Comment: how is your user entity connected to this?

Comment: I am using AccountController to show the list of users in index page. so I added  `private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;` as a member and adding it to constructor to assign _context. so I am trying to to use  `_context.Users` in other functions.

Comment: and that User member of your context is a DbSet<ApplicationUser> ?

Comment: Nope that is not a member but it inherits here too. `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`..

Comment: then what type is _context.User?

Comment: var xx = from u in _context.Users.Select(x => new ApplicationUserList { Firstname = x.Firstname, RoleType = (Roles)x.RoleId }); 
// I am trying to use your method. but negative ans. "Cannot implicitly convert type Roles to string" . This role type is a string to hold the description in class  ApplicationUserList which is a viewmodel class.

Comment: see edit ... if you can not implicitly convert something... do it explicitly

Answer (score 1):

```
// This join is performed in memory
var results =
    from e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Roles)).Cast<Roles>()
    join r in ApplicationUser on e equals r.Roles into rs
    from r in rs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Roles = e, Count = r?.Count ?? 0};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you should first convert enum to dictionary an Join between what you need, here is an example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ApplicationUser a = new ApplicationUser();
        a.userName = "a";
        a.role = 1;

        ApplicationUser b = new ApplicationUser();
        b.userName = "b";
        b.role = 3;

        List<ApplicationUser> alist=new List<ApplicationUser>();
        alist.Add(a);
        alist.Add(b);

        Dictionary<int, string> DicRoles = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var vals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Roles));

        foreach (var val in vals)
        {
            DicRoles.Add((int)val, val.ToString());
        }

        var result = from t in alist
                     join x in DicRoles on t.role equals x.Key
                     select new {t.userName,x.Value };


    }

    public enum Roles:int
    {
        Administrator = 1,
        Headquarters = 2,
        Branch = 3,
        Driver = 4,
        Client = 5
    }
}

public class ApplicationUser
{
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public int role { get; set; }
}
```